# Flutter - Why is child widget's initState() is not called on every rebuild of Parent widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a `Parent` widget, which holds some state, a counter in this case.

This state is passed on to a `Child` widget using its constructor.

Now, how I understand it, the `Child` should get re-built every-time `Parent`'s state changes, since it's inside the `build()` function of `Parent`, and `build()` gets called every-time the state changes.

This concept lead me to believe that the `INIT STATE!` message would be printed every time the counter changes. But it is not the case!

I essentially want a "hook" that gets fired only once, whenever the `Child`'s constructor arguments (`message`) change.

Can someone please explain why this is the case, and what is the right way to have the aforementioned "hook"?

```
class Child extends StatefulWidget {
  final String message;

  const Child(this.message, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChildState createState() => _ChildState();
}

class _ChildState extends State<Child> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    print("INIT STATE!");
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(widget.message),
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentState createState() => _ParentState();
}

class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _counter += 1;
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Child(_counter.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: https://flutterbyexample.com/stateful-widget-lifecycle/#6-didupdatewidget

Comment: @anmol.majhail your suggested link is broken, kindly update or remove it from here. Thanks

Comment: The updated link is https://flutterbyexample.com/lesson/stateful-widget-lifecycle#6-didupdatewidget

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Ok, looks like this was clearly mentioned in the [State](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) class' docs.

The correct way to do this is to override the `didUpdateWidget` method in the `State` subclass.

Answer (score 23):

Thanks to @Dev Aggarwal.

Extending to Dev Aggarwal's answer, i have included example here.

Implement didUpdateWidget() method in Child widget. When ever parent state changed, didUpdateWidget() method will call in child widget.

```
Implement didUpdateWidget() method in Child widget.

@override
  void didUpdateWidget(<YourChildScreen> oldWidget) {

    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    print("oldWidget.searchTerm is ${oldWidget.searchTerm}");
    print("widget.searchTerm is ${widget.searchTerm}");

    if (oldWidget.searchTerm != widget.searchTerm) {

      this.updateChildWithParent();

    }
  }


void updateChildWithParent() {
    print("updateChildWithParent/search screen");
    setState(() {

      _mJsonLoaded = false; // For loader
      if (listArray.length > 0) {
        listArray.clear();
      }
    });

    // Do whatever you want here…
    // Like call api call again in child widget.
  }
```

I hope it will useful.

Comment: Thanks Mahesh for the example! Just one detailt: as stated in didUpdateWidget docs (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html), calling to setState() in that functions is redundant, as it's always executed before the build() method of the widget.

Answer (score 5):

`initState` is called only when the state is first inserted in the widget tree. Later on, it's the `didUpdateWidget` which handles the subsequent calls.