# How to Invoke initState() method of child widget from parent widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, state, bloc

I want to call initState() method of child widget from parent stateful widget.

Here is my Code:

```
class ClassA extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ClassAState createState() => _ClassAState();
}

class _ClassAState extends State<ClassA> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ClassB(),
            InkWell(
              child: Text('Call ClassB initState()'),
              onTap: (){
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
      ,
    );
  }
}

class ClassB extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ClassBState createState() => _ClassBState();
}

class _ClassBState extends State<ClassB> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('initState in ClassB');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 100,
      child: Text('Class B'),
    );
  }
}
```

In above i want to invoke ClassB initState() method from ClassA(). But On tap, it invokes only the build method of class B but I also want to invoke initState().

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - Why is child widget's initState() is not called on every rebuild of Parent widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54759920/flutter-why-is-child-widgets-initstate-is-not-called-on-every-rebuild-of-pa)

Comment: No, I can't solved my question by referring to that.

Comment: "In above i want to invoke ClassB initState() method from ClassA(). "  You should not do that, want to do that, or need to do that.  Learn more about the StatefulWidget patterns, and read some more code.

Comment: I invoke the setState method on button click so rebuild the ClassA and ClassB. First-time ClassA loaded ClassB initState is invoked. But rebuilding ClassA usning setState() method not inovking ClassB initState().

Answer (score -1):

*ClassA* and *ClassB* has 2 different internal state. On the first run the two widget are insert into the tree so every *initState* is called. After that if you call *setState* in *ClassA* you are changing *ClassA* state. If you look at documentation

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html

> Called when this object is inserted into the tree.
>
> The framework will call this method exactly once for each State object
> it creates.
>
> Override this method to perform initialization that depends on the
> location at which this object was inserted into the tree (i.e.,
> context) or on the widget used to configure this object (i.e.,
> widget).

You can see that *initState* is called by the framework only once, so isn't the right method to manipulate the state of *ClassB* once it is already initialized. As Randal Schwartz suggested you should change your code. You can start here

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive

Comment: this answer answers some other question not the one in question